# Git push witihin local filesystem; viable workflow solution?

Tags: git, version-control

Say I have a Git repo folder where I do all my development. The master branch represents the production code and any development is merged in from different branches, as required. That's all fine. What if, now, I wanted to push the master branch somewhere within my local filesystem (e.g., a sibling folder), whenever I want to roll the master branch out to production?

Is this possible, with Git? For instance, say I have my project in `~/development/myProject-dev`, can I push just the master branch into `~/development/myProject` as a live mirror; that is, `~/development/myProject` is publicly accessible, whereas its `-dev` brother has restricted access?

If this is fine, it seems like a good solution because `~/development/myProject` will also be a repo and can always be rolled back to a stable state, if say the changes made in development introduced a bug. Would you agree that this is a viable workflow? Are there better approaches (e.g., Git hooks, etc.)?

Comment: It seems you are looking for http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#Local-Protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can push can do pulls and pushes locally with git. You can also clone only one branch into a new repository:

```
git clone ~/development/myProject-dev -b master ~/development/myProject
```

This command should clone *only* the master branch from your myProject-dev repo.

Comment: Are there any advantages of clone over push (or vice versa) in this instance?

Comment: I believe that a 'clone' is very similar to a 'init' followed by a 'pull' (plus adding a remote called "origin"). After you have done either of these you will need to keep it up to date with the origin by doing 'git pull origin master'

Comment: Ah, I see: So you control the mirroring from the mirror, so to speak, rather than pushing from `myProject-dev` whenever necessary?

Comment: Exactly, you push from the original and pull from the other